# how to use Hugo with github pages to automatically update content

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I am using Hugo to deploy a static page to github pages

I have a git repo in the `/public` folder but the contents of the `/static` folder are not a part of the repository. Therfore they are not uploaded to the `username.github.io` page.

the `/static` folder contains images and css files. This is why my page does not look good after pushing to github.

My workaround is that each time I manually copy the `/static` folder into the `/public` folder after I build the site.

I think there should be  a better solution and I am probably missing something in the `config.toml` file of the hugo workflow.

I am following the instructions from [this site](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html)

Any ideas how to automatically include `/static` files into the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hugo copies all the files in the `static/` directory into the `public/` directory when your site is rendered. For example, if you have a `static/` folder that looks like this:

```
.
├── css
│   └── main.css
└── img
    ├── favicon.png
    └── avatar.png
```

Then when you build your site, the `public/` folder will look like this:

```
.
├── css
│   ├── main.css
│   └── <theme css files>
├── img
│     ├── favicon.png
│     ├── avatar.png
│     └── <theme images>
<more content folders>
```

So the files in your static folder are probably being included already. The problem is likely to be that your theme is looking for your static files in the wrong place. Take a look at your theme documentation and see if it says anything about static assets.